# appengine migration from python 2 to python 3 tips

Tags: python, google-app-engine, migration

I am using the google-endpoints library for my rest api on an appengine app.
The lib is tested only on Python27 but on January 1st, Python27 is deprecated and I want to migrate to Python3.

Do I have to use a framework like Flask or Django to pursue my migration or should I find a substitute for the google-endpoints library?

I tried to use Flask and it works but I would have to rewrite a lot of code.

Answer (score 0):

It would be hard to fully answer your question without knowing a lot more about your specific use of that library, but I would generally recommend finding a replacement because it isn't being actively developed. You will likely have to rewrite a lot of your code because that library is not likely to be updated to Python3 and beyond.

I would recommend checking out [OpenAPI](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/openapi-overview) and a Python extension that supports it such as Flask and [Flask-swagger](https://github.com/gangverk/flask-swagger).

Answer (score 0):

When **migrating** your application from Python 2 to Python 3 on the App Engine standard environment, you should be aware of the following **differences**:

- [Compatibility issues between Python 2 and Python 3](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/python-differences#compat)
- [Fewer restrictionson the runtime environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/python-differences#restrictions)
- [No App Engine APIs, changes to app.yaml, and local development](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/python-differences#env)

The official **Google Cloud Platform** documentation has an article called "[Understanding differences between the Python 2 and Python 3 environments](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/python-differences)", which you can use for a reference when migrating.

Regarding the **Endpoints Frameworks**, they're not supported in Python 3.x environment yet. As an option, you can take a look at the [App Engine flexible](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-app-engine#top_of_page) environment, since you would be able to use the Google Cloud Endpoints there.